# Programatically select node in TreeView

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm working in a UWP application with a TreeView.

I need to select or deselect a node in the TreeView in response to the user clicking an unrelated button elsewhere in my app.

I know exactly which node I want to select, but can't find a way to do it: the TreeView only appears to have the option to SelectAll, or to get the SelectedNodes and Clear them all.

I think the solution might be to add or remove the node I want from the SelectedNodes list, however, the items in this list are of type TreeViewNode and I don't know how to get the TreeViewNode for the item I want. (I populated the list by handing it an ObservableCollection of my own data type).

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Please post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you currently have.

Comment: Could you tell us which SelectionMode you are using, Single or Multiple mode? If you want to get the specified TreeViewNode, you could try to get the root node by using TreeView.RootNodes first, and then use TreeViewNode.Children to get a child node. In addition, can you provide the code snippet about what you currently implement and which node you want to select/unselect?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of is to use the [WinUI TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.treeview?view=winui-2.4).

Then you can just set the `SelectedItem` property like this:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTreeView.SelectedItem = nodeToSelect;
}
```

If you haven't used WinUI before, please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started).